# Windows Service Failure with setup.exe

Tags: windows-services

I'm having an issue with a windows service. The (un)install with installUtil is working fine.

But (after uninstalling my service), I want to install it with the setup.exe I generated, I get the following error message:

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows
>   service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then
>   started with the Server Explorer, Windows Services Administrative Tool
>   or the NET START command.

I'm a bit confused because it's working fine with the manual installation.
I need this setup.exe to install the windows service properly as I'm going to give that out to someone else to install it.

The code to start the service is the following

```
Shareed Sub Main()
            Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

     ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New MySERVICE}
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
```

Comment: Somehow, your `setup.exe` is actually your service executable rather than an installer.  (It is possible for a single executable to be both, but this depends on the language and/or platform.)